# How can I change fullcalendar event start/end time when create on select

Tags: fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using fullcalendar with this `select` callback function in settings object:

```
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
            // slotDuration: '00:10:00',
            allDayDefault: false,
            editable: true 
            selectable: true,
            select: function(start, end, jsEvent, view) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: moment(start).hour(12),
                        end: moment(end).hour(18),
                        editable: true
                    };

                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');                
                // $('div#event-editor').modal({ show: true });
            });
```

The problem is that `moment(end).hour(18)` ads 18 hours to the end moment, causing an increased time until the event is finished. I need a function to effectively set the moment hour to '18' instead of '00'.

Comment: Sorry but still unclear what you are trying to achieve with the select: callback.

Comment: the `select` callback is fired when a user click on a day (or a hour) in month/day/agenda view and prompt for an `Event Title` . In my script the begining time of the event is at hour `00:00` for `start` and `23:59` for `end` . I try to figure out the time (HH:mm) of `start` and `end` object . I mean I wanna change the default hours, but with the `.hour()` method, the hour isn't changes. that method effectively **add** an amount of hours equal to the number passed to it.

Comment: Never saw select being used that way, I'd use dayClick instead. I haven't tried the hour function, but I'm using .add('hours', 18) - can you see if it changes anything?

Comment: I'm using select that way because I wanna let the user to instantly create events that span multiple days. I'll try to limit the event creation to one single day using `dayClick`. Yes the `.add('hours',18)` add 18 hours to the end of event time wich is 23:59 by default for the `moment`.`end`.